# Cocoapods does not create framework target for Google analytics

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My cocoapods file specifies Google Analytics framework target for my project

```
use_frameworks!
pod "Google/Analytics"
```

However after the pod is installed, I cannot see the GoogleAnalytics framework target generated, and I still need to import the Google Analytics header in my bridging header file. What did I miss here?

Comment: Have u update the cocoa pod.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior as it is a **pre-compiled** framework. There is no need for a target if there are no sources to compile.

Comment: so how to fix: "target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries"?